# Convert metric value from number to string

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm using Grafana table panel to show status of my application.
Currently in Prometheus metrics, I'm returning 1 and 0. Where, 1 mean pass and 0 means fail.

On table view it is also showing as 0 & 1.
Can I change the Prometheus query to return 'PASS' when value is 1, 'FAIL' otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar for a graph. I had to convert `int` value to `text` for `metric`. I managed the situation by converting the value to `text` by using `CAST`. Simply use the `CAST` in your `metric` column. Please note that, I'm using PostgreSQL as a DataSource.

Please check below image for the casting example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should look the way to change the display in Grafana.

- Under Edit option of the panel
- Check the overrides option where you can select

  1. Override fields with name and select value mappings
  2. Add Value mappings as per your requirement

[image]

I have also took the screenshot as per the numbers for your reference.